# How to calculate Numbers without rounding? Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, numbers, long-integer

How can i calculate like this without rounding up or down ?

```
Dim gesamtpreis As Long = TextBox2.Text * TextBox3.Text
```

When you calculate `1 * 17.90` then the Result is 18 ? But should be 17,90

And when you calculate `1,5 * 17.90` then the Result is 27  but it should be 26,85

So how can i fix this ?

Comment: To start with, make sure you use `Option Strict On` with all of your VB code. Then your line won't work so you'll have to do this: `Dim gesamtpreis As Double = Double.Parse(TextBox2.Text) * Double.Parse(TextBox3.Text)`.

Comment: @Enigmativity Okey works fine :) But how can i fix it that it dont delete the Zero -> Example : 17,90 is then 17,9

Comment: It's not deleting the zero.  Numbers have no leading or trailing zeroes.  If you want to display them then you have to add them when you convert the number to a `String`.  The `ToString` method of your `Double` value allows you to specify an output format.

Comment: @jmcilhinney for me it is deleting it? Or do i understand you false?  Can you give me a Example ?

Comment: No, it's not deleting it.  I'm not suggesting that the zero is there in the output.  I'm suggesting that it was never there in the input.  You are converting a `String` to a `Double` because you can only perform arithmetic operations on numbers.  As I said, numbers do not have leading or trailing spaces.  After you do your arithmetic, you convert the result to a `String` for display.  If you want that `String` to have leading or trailing spaces then you have to add them yourself because they won't magically appear.

Comment: @Hanselman - The number `17.9` doesn't have a trailing zero unless we explicitly want to display it that way. You would need to do `Dim gesamtpreis As String = (Double.Parse(TextBox2.Text) * Double.Parse(TextBox3.Text)).ToString("0.00")`, but now your result is a string and no longer a number.

Comment: @Enigmativity still only 17,9 not 17,90

Comment: @Hanselman - This simple test - `(179.0 * 0.1).ToString("0.00")` - produces the result `17.90` for me. Can you try this test yourself?

Comment: @Hanselman - Please make sure you you also have `Option Strict On` at the top of your code.

Comment: @Enigmativity LOL!  Yours is working but mine not wtf ?     MsgBox((1 * 17.9).ToString("0.00"))

        Dim gesamtpreis As Double = CDbl((CDbl(TextBox2.Text) * CDbl(TextBox3.Text)).ToString("0.00"))

Comment: @Hanselman - Because you're calling `CDbl(...)` on the result. That will turn the `"17.90"` into `17.9` again. If you want to retain the final zero you must leave it as a string.

Comment: I tried but i dont get it :o ! Can you give me the correct code ?